# my weight is "doubled" yours

Tags: word-usage

If one was meaning to say that their weight was the double of mine / twice mine, could this expression be acceptable: my weight is doubled yours?

I don't think so, but I need to settle some internet argument :D

Comment: Short answer: no. Either: my weight is double yours, or my weight is yours doubled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the [postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective) is placed AFTER the noun in say:

> mine halve**d**, yours double**d**

against the prepositive

> half mine, double/twice yours

the adjective can be said to be referring to a noun that has already happened, and so requires a past-tense suffix of **d** to make sense, and to use the **d** beforehand, as you have done, therefore doesn't scan well.